# Predicting SVM model with regressors

Tags: r, svm, predict

I am predicting a SVM model for the electricity load of two months in 2016. The training dataset contains data from 2012 - 2016. I have added a set of regressors into my dataset, but when predicting it returns a prediction of the data from 2012-2016 in stead of the first month of 2016. What am I doing wrong?

code used:

```
svm.model <- svm(NLtraints~NLxreg, data = NLtraints, type = "nu-regression")

fcastsvmjan <- predict(svm.model, xreg = NLxregjan, data =NLjants)
```

Characteristics of variables:

```
 str(NLxregjan)
 num [1:31, 1:11] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:31] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" ...

str(NLtraints)
Time-Series [1:1461] from 2012 to 2016: 958944 1173768 1242864 1234788 1238140 ...

str(NLjants) 
Time-Series [1:31] from 2016 to 2017: 966160 1055384 1017592 1215048 1235760 ...

str(NLxreg)
num [1:1461, 1:11] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:1461] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" ...
```

Comment: Respecting SMV modeling, I was using predict with parameters `model` and `newData`, like `fcastsvmjan <- predict(svm.model, newData = NLxregjan)` I don't think you have to provide NLjants

Comment: Maybe it's more useful to apply a Time Series fitting instead of a SVM as for example AR, MA, ARMA, ARIMA,...mathematically considered

Comment: @wolf_wue I still get the prediction for the entire dataset.. I am trying to compare methods, as such I will need to perform the SVM as well.